# Finding information about a Java class without documentation

Tags: java, class, jar

As part of a project I am working on I am required to use a class to write serialized data to a file, but all I have been presented with is the `.jar` file and a rather opaque usage example. Is there any way I can glean some information on it, such as inherited class and public methods?

Comment: Decompile and [Learn to Read the Source, Luke](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/04/learn-to-read-the-source-luke.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can unzip the jar using `jar xf {jarname}` and then use a [decompiler](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/) on the relevant file(s). It won't give you the source, but you will get the structure, field names etc.

Comment: How do I download the plugin? All I get is a french web site but I can't see any "download now" button :-/

Comment: @Davz: 1. That's the UI and not the (Eclipse) plugin. 2. It doesn't answer my question :-)

Comment: Ok, here is the answer: When you click one of the download links, you will end up on a french web page. After about 10 seconds, a button with this text will appear: `Valider et télécharger le fichier` Click that to download the file.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Turns out, for some reason, it just contains a Hashtable and has renamed `put` with `add`.

Answer (score 1):

Your IDE should be able to tell you all this. Just create an instance of the class and type
`inst.` <kbd>Ctrl+Space</kbd>

You should now see a list of public fields and methods. If that doesn't work, try `javap` to dump the API of the class (there are also options to dump the byte code) or a Java decompiler like [jad](http://www.varaneckas.com/jad/)

Comment: I use TextMate rather than an IDE! A decompiler sounds perfect though.

Comment: I would strongly recommend an IDE. The ability to navigate the codebase is worth whatever learning curve is required

Comment: @BrianAgnew: +1 Using a text editor to develop software is like using a fork to dig a tunnel. Yeah, it works ...

Answer (score 0):

Go to your java JDK directory (i.e C:\Dev\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\bin) use command jar xf "jar_name".
Than go to [Download JAD](http://www.varaneckas.com/jad/) and download decompiler. Then decompile classes from unziped jar.